# Remove spacing between colums in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I want to remove the spacing between 2 div colums.

Code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2"><b>Text1</b></div>
    <div class="col-2"><b>Text2</b></div>
</div>
```

and it ends in:

[_________]  "space space......" [___________]

I know that there are some solution here, I tried to remove padding, margin, but nothing worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: What space are you talking about?

Comment: We didn't see no spaces, you must add a fiddle or any other live example...

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap? You can change the `@grid-gutter-width` variable via either the online customizer or by using the LESS source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'technical' term for the space between each `.col-` in the Bootstrap framework is 'gutter' and this gutter is achieved through the use of padding.

If you are using v3.x of Bootstrap you'll need to create a custom class:

```
.no-gutter {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.no-gutter > [class*="col-"] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

And apply that to any `.row` where you want there to be no gutters.  Bootstrap 4 has a native `.no-gutters` class that achieves the same results.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#no-gutters